# copy different file names from a computer to san map drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What is the proper syntax in powershell?  I'm trying to copy different file names from a pc drive "D" folder to a san mapped drive folder, but unsuccessful. Below is a generic example of 3 files, where ip address = 10.10.0.0, h is the map letter drive to the san. Thank you for your help.

```
 copy-item \\10.10.0.0\D$\folder1\folder2\ "filename1.20170814", 
 "002file.05172017", "name123.log"  H:\folder_a\folder_b\ -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest specifying parameters explicitly instead of implicitly if you're unsure.

```
$Params = @{
  Path        = '\\10.10.0.0\D$\folder1\folder2'
  Destination = 'H:\folder_a\folder_b'
  Include     = @('filename1.20170814','002file.05172017','name123.log')
  Recurse     = $True
}
Copy-Item @Params
```

---

PSv2 edit:

```
Copy-Item -Path '\\10.10.0.0\D$\folder1\folder2'`
          -Destination 'H:\folder_a\folder_b'`
          -Include 'filename1.20170814','002file.05172017','name123.log'`
          -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank you, @Thelncorrigible1. Tried suggested code executes with no error. However, I do not see the files copied in the destination folder. To make sure, I checked my syntax  and destination folder name. I'm running Powershell version: Major =2, Minor=0, Build = -1, Revision=-1.

Comment: That would be a problem as splatting didn't get introduced until v3.  Is there a reason you're still on v2?  I adjusted my answer with an alternative

Comment: Thank you @Thelconrrigible1. It is not my system. but asking them to upgrade to a higher Powershell version. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Thelncorrigible1, tried the PSV2 in my local computer as a test. Executed ok, but it does not copy the files to "folder _a\folder_b" as follows:                  
           Copy-Item -Path 'C:\folder1\folder2'`
          -Destination 'D:\folder_a\folder_b'`
          -Include 'filename1.txt','name123.log'`
          -Recurse

Comment: @BenQ Try using the `-Verbose` switch and report back on what the cmdlet is doing

Comment: @TheInconrrigible1 sorry but what is the syntax to declare the -Verbose in the above statements. Tried different ways, but did no result. Thanks.